# What happens if my current residence permit expires before my application for a new one is processed?

Tags: working-visas, france, residence-cards

I am a non-EU citizen with a residence permit in France expiring some day soon.

I have started the application for a new residence permit (and I believe I have the right documents, if that's relevant).

However, the French authority (the Prefecture) has not processed my application for a residence permit yet. All I have for proof is a PDF saying that I submitted an application.

I have followed France's guideline of applying for a residence permit (i.e. at least two months before my current one expires). However, it has been two months since I made my application and they have not yet gotten back to me.

Can I stay in France / EU with an expired residence permit but with this PDF proof that I have an application waiting?

I have looked at the other possibly relevant topics but my question has not been answered as most of them ask about travelling. My question is about staying while waiting.